# Can I convert a meeting in Outlook to a Skype meeting?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, skype

I have a recurring meeting in my calendar which I'll have to do over Skype this week. Is there any way to convert one of the occurrences of the meeting into a Skype meeting, without creating a new meeting?

Some cursory inspection of the toolbars in Outlook suggests it is not, but I feel this is an option which should be there?

[image: Outlook Meeting Ribbons]

Comment: Related post - [Recover the missing Skype meeting URL of a Skype meeting invite](https://superuser.com/q/1420902/374397)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to my understanding Skype meetings are just the same object as any other meeting, just they have a link to a Skype (for business) meeting.

What you need to do is just create a new Skype meeting and copy it's link to your existing meeting instance, then delete the new meeting object.

Comment: You don't need to create a whole new skype meeting to get the link.  Use the steps to add the Skype icon to the ribbon bar or quick launch bar in outlook as suggested by "anonymous"'s answer.  Then you can open the meeting, click the skype meeting button and it adds the link for you.

Answer (score 17):

According to a comment in the thread [Skype meeting can't been inserted into the outlook meeting invite which was already scheduled](https://www.skypefeedback.com/forums/299913-generally-available/suggestions/10740297-skype-meeting-can-t-been-inserted-into-the-outlook):

> Modify your Quick Access Toolbar in a Meeting Occurrence and add the Skype Meeting Command to do this.
>
> 1. Open a meeting occurrence
> 2. Customize the toolbar (more commands -> Meeting Occurrence tab).
>
>    [image: Outlook Options]
> 3. Find the 'Skype Meeting' command and add it to the toolbar.
> 4. Click OK.
> 5. Click the command from the toolbar and Skype meeting will be added to your existing meeting.
>
>    [image: Skype Meeting in Quick Toolbar]