# Recover the missing Skype meeting URL of a Skype meeting invite

Tags: microsoft-outlook, skype-for-business, meeting-request

I created a new recurring meeting invite using Outlook.  I converted it into a Skype meeting invite.

So it added all the meeting URL and dial in details into the meeting description. Then I realized that I want it to be a normal meeting (non-Skype). So I deleted the entire description. I thought that deleting the description will convert it into a normal meeting (I was wrong though). I sent out the invite to all the participants with blank meeting description.

Now I want to add the Skype meeting URL again into the description and send an update on the original meeting invite. The link pointed by `Join Skype Meeting` shown in the screenshot below when I was creating the meeting invite for the first time:

[image]

But I've no way to retrieve it. Can someone suggest on how to retrieve the missing Skype meeting URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to RBT, ioin the meeting you scheduled in the previous step. The Skype for Business meeting window has a round "..." button at the bottom right corner of the window. Click the button and choose the Meeting Entry Info option from the context menu. The dialog that opens shows a Meeting Link field which contains the URL that you'll use to join the meeting

[image]

Check this link:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/appsdk/getmeetingurl

Comment: This is the real answer. I can also copy the link so easily. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a way for the same. I'm using Outlook from Office 365

1. Open the meeting, either an occurrence or the series.
2. Go to `Meeting Occurrence` tab
3. The meeting description wasn't showing any Skype meeting URL.
4. Hover your mouse over `Join Skype meeting` button in the toolbar.
5. The meeting URL is shown in the tool-tip. You will note it down manually though as Windows doesn't allow copying content from tool-tip:

   [image]
6. This meeting URL is very helpful as anyone can join the meeting by browsing the URL in a web-browser